# $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_2(n) = n + {n-1\over2^2} + {n-3\over 3^2} + \ldots + {1 \over n^2}$ : surely infinite, but related to something?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I have the series $ \small b = 1 + (1+ \frac 14) + (1 + \frac 14 + \frac 19) + \ldots $, where the partial sums are
$$ s_2(n) = n + {n-1\over2^2} + {n-2\over 3^2} + \ldots + {1 \over n^2}$$ 
This series occurs in context with a generalization of the Eulerian numbers, which I've mentioned in this [MO-thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10124/the-factorial-of-1-2-3/32302#32302). It looks, as if it is related to the simpler series $ \small a = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 + ... $whose partial sums are:
$$ s_1(n) = 1 + {1\over2} + {1\over 3} + \ldots + {1 \over n}$$ where of course the limit as $ n \to \infty$ is infinite.

Question: can I relate the two (underlying) series (a,b) by some formal algebraic manipulation?

It might be, that the series with alternating signs can be related through the Dirichlet $\eta$- (or "alternating $\zeta$"), as shown in my linked answer in MO, but I don't see at the moment how I can support such a guess.

Comment: There's the obvious $s_2(n) + s_1(n) = (n+1)\cdot (1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{n^2})$, and analogous for alternating signs. I guess that's not the kind of thing you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $s_2(n)=(n+1)\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}=(n+1)\frac{\pi^2}6-(n+1)\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}-H_n$ with $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}$ (and $H_n$ the $n$th harmonic number is also your $s_1(n)$).

Since $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac1n+o\left(\frac1n\right)$ and $H_n=\log n+\gamma+o(1)$, one gets
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(s_2(n)-n\frac{\pi^2}6+\log n\right)=\frac{\pi^2}6-1-\gamma.
$$
Note that the constants involved are $\frac{\pi^2}6=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\zeta(2)$ and $\gamma=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)-\log n$.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it makes sense to replace the $ \pi^2 /6$ by the reference to $\zeta(2)$ and $\gamma$ to the Ramanujan-normalization of $\zeta(1)$ - because it might be, that that type of relations occur with higher orders of that series types as given in my MO-link (and involves then $\zeta(3)$ et. al.)? *(However, before I can really say this, I've to work with your ansatz myself)*

Comment: OK. What are the higher order relations you have in mind? This is not clear from the MO page you link to.

Comment: Well, I've asked for a formal algebraic relation between the series made of the entries of the generalized Eulerian triangle are row-indexes $-1$ and $-2$ (where I've speculated a relation similar to the $\Gamma$'s at negative arguments (which are for instance also discussed by D. Loeb as *Roman's* and *Knuth's* gamma-generalizations)). Next natural question is that of some formal algebraic relation of the series by the terms at indexes $-2$ and $-3$ and so on. *(But I'll be happy if I can solve my first question so far)*

Comment: *An arXiv-link to the discussion of D Loeb, which I came across only today is http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9502218v1 .*

Comment: Dear Did, I've again asked that question a couple of days ago to get more input. I am not sure, whether in that lim-parenthese there is no further cancellation with a residue. If you are interested (or can contribute again) please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956249/regularized-sum-of-11-frac122-1-frac122-frac132-cdots-or