# Regularized sum of $1+(1+\frac1{2^2}) + (1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2})+\cdots$, or $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^k\frac1{j^2}$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, divergent-series, regularization

For my exercises on divergent summation I try to find a regularization of
$$   S^{^\star}_2 \underset{\mathcal R}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^k \frac1{j^2} \tag 1
$$
It is not difficult to derive the formula for the partial sums introducing the harmonic numbers of order $1$ and $2$
$$H_1(N)=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1{k} \\
  H_2(N)=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1{k^2} \tag {2.1}$$
and writing
$$ S_2(N) = (N+1) \cdot H_2(N) - H_1(N) \tag {2.2}$$
When going to the limit $N \to \infty$ and the serial summation according to eq 2.1 cannot be done, we can -using the $\psi$ (or "digamma", in Pari/GP  `psi(1+N)`)-function-   approximate  $$H_1(N) \sim \gamma + \psi(1+N)  \tag {3.1}$$  and for $H_2(N)$ the derivative of the $\psi()$:
$$ H_2(N) \sim \zeta(2)-\psi^{(1)}(1+N) \tag {3.2}
$$

I don't see how I can proceed now. I'd assume for the regularization in the case for $N$ in the limit I can use $\gamma$ for the $H_1^{^\star}$.

> **Q:But how can I the do the $H_2$-part for the limit formula for eq (3.2) resp. (2.2)?**

---

A bit background: In a [treatize on the triangle of Eulerian numbers](http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/01_12_Eulermatrix.pdf) (pg.8) I hand-waving-generalize the triangle towards negative row numbers, and for the row-sum of the $-2$'nd row I get those formal sums.
[image: picture]

---

***update*** I just found my 2013-question about the same subject, and there was an answer but which I could not then believe it is a final answer, and still I'm unsure whether (and how) I can proceed to a "fixed statement" see [earlierquestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438828/1714) The user @did gave the answer
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(s_2(n)-n\frac{\pi^2}6+\log n\right)=\frac{\pi^2}6-1-\gamma \qquad \text{introduced by me: } =\zeta(2)-1 - \gamma
$$

Comment: $\sum _{k=1}^m H_k^{(2)}=-\gamma +H_{1+m}^{(2)}+m H_{1+m}^{(2)}-\psi ^{(0)}(2+m)$ 
 and throw away the divergent part ,looks like the answer is:$-\gamma$

Comment: @Mariusz, that would mean $\Gamma(0)/(-1)$ and would well fit in the scheme of the table. Hope that value comes out when checked rigorously...

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: It's 
$$\sum_{k=1}^m H^{(2)}_k = (m+1) H_m^{(2)} - H_m = (m+1)\zeta(2) - \log m - \gamma - 1 + {\cal O}(1/m) \, .$$
However, cut-off regularization seems to be problematic, since you can basically just change the result by substituting m→m+c for any constant $c$, so you a-priori don't know which constants are the correct ones and which aren't, or?

Comment: Just writing a comment including " @Did  " who is mentioned in the question... The atsign does not seem to alert the user if the atsign is not in a comment

Comment: @peterag - thanks for the hint! I've pinged the user did separately at his old answer.

Answer (score 3):

Regularizing the sum when the analytically continued function has a pole at the value of interest for the parameter, does not seem to give a unique value. There are several options to regularize:

1. You could introduce a variable $x$ to make it a power-series s.t. the series converges for $|x|<1$ i.e.
   $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j^2} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2} \sum_{k=j}^\infty x^k = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2} \frac{x^j}{1-x} = \frac{{\rm Li_2}(x)}{1-x} \, .$$ Finally expand the polylogarithm about $x=1$ using the polylogarithm identity https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12 mentioned in the comments, which gives $$\frac{{\rm Li_2}(x)}{1-x} = \frac{-{\rm Li_2}(1-x) + \zeta(2) - \log(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x} \\ = \frac{\zeta(2)}{1-x} + \log(1-x) - 1 + {\cal O}\left( (1-x)\log(1-x) \right)$$
   for $x\rightarrow 1$. Hence, when the bare singularities are discarded you arrive at $-1$.
2. Cut-Off regularization introduces an upper limit $m$ into the sum and the result is then expanded in terms of the cut-off. This gives $$\sum_{k=1}^m H^{(2)}_k = (m+1) H_m^{(2)} - H_m = (m+1)\zeta(2) - \log (m) - \gamma - 1 + {\cal O}(1/m) \, .$$ The divergent parts in $m$ can be viewed as singularities at $\infty$ and are of the same type as in the first method for $x\rightarrow 1^{-}$. The constant term differs and reads $\zeta(2) - \gamma - 1$.
3. Zeta functional regularization is another commonly applied procedure to treat infinities. The generalized zeta-function which converges for $\Re(s)>1$ is sought to be continued to $s=0$. Since $s=1$ has convergence issues, the analytically continued version will turn out to have a pole at $s=1$. Therefore we first continue to $\Re(s)>0$ by simple manipulation
   \begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^s} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-s} \sum_{j=1}^k j^{-2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-s} \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{-2} - \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty j^{-2} \right)  \\ &= \zeta(2) \zeta(s) + \zeta(s+2) - \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-s} \sum_{j=k}^\infty j^{-2} \\ &= \zeta(2) \zeta(s) + \zeta(s+2) - \sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{-2} \sum_{k=1}^j k^{-s} \, . \end{align}
   The Zeta-function of the first term has the aforementioned pole at $s=1$ and can be easily continued to $s=0$ and the rightmost sum is now convergent for $\Re(s)>0$ which implies there to be another pole at $s=0$. To shift the convergence further to the left in the complex plane we now introduce $$k^{-s} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-kx} \, {\rm d}x$$
   into the last term, which in turn becomes (after interchanging summation and integration)
   \begin{align} \sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{-2} \sum_{k=1}^j k^{-s} &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, x^{s-1} \sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{-2} \sum_{k=1}^j e^{-kx} \\ &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, x^{s-1} \sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{-2} \, \frac{1-e^{-jx}}{e^x-1} \\ &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, x^{s-1} \, \frac{\zeta(2)-{\rm Li_2}\left(e^{-x}\right)}{e^x-1} \\ &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, x^{s-1} \, \frac{{\rm Li_2}\left(1-e^{-x}\right)-x \log\left( 1-e^{-x} \right)}{e^x-1}  \, , \end{align}
   where in the last step the aforementioned polylogarithm identity was used. The integral converges like the sum for $\Re(s)>0$ and each term of the integral converges separately. The restriction follows from the behaviour at $x=0$. Because of the $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ it suffices to extract the singularities at $s=0$, since any finite contribution will vanish in the limit $s\rightarrow 0$. To do this, we subtract and add the leading behaviour  of the nominator for $x\rightarrow 0$ \begin{align} {\rm Li_2}\left(1-e^{-x}\right) &= x + {\cal O}(x^2)  \\ \log\left(1-e^{-x}\right) &= \log(x) + {\cal O}(x) \, . \end{align}
   After the leading terms have been subtracted, the resulting integral converges for $\Re(s)>-1$, i.e. it is finite at $s=0$. Hence it suffices to calculate $$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, x^{s-1} \, \frac{x-x \log\left( x \right)}{e^x-1} \\ = \frac{s}{\Gamma(s+1)} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^s}{e^x-1} \, {\rm d}x - \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^s}{e^x-1} \, \log(x) \, {\rm d}x \\ = s \, \zeta(s+1) - \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}s} \Gamma(s+1)\zeta(s+1) \\ = 1 + \frac{1}{s} + \gamma + {\cal O}(s) $$
   where the integral representation of the Zeta function was used from the second to the third line. Evidently there is no logarithmic singularity like in the other two cases, but they all share the leading pole singularity. The constant term in this case after using the well known result $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ finally reads $\frac{\zeta(2)}{2} - \gamma - 1$.

What's the moral of the story? When the analytically continued version of the to be regularized sum contains a pole at the value in question, the result can be more or less anything. Only when the analytically continued value is finite, it is also unique. You can also see the arbitrariness for instance when you substitute $m \rightarrow m+c$ in the second case, or $x \rightarrow \frac{x + c (1-x)}{1+c(1-x)}$ in the first case, for any constant $c$.

Comment: Ah, this reads meaningful and looks very nice! I'll try this numerically with Pari/GP...

Comment: I get for $\lim_{h\to 0}( \Gamma(-1+h) -\frac1h) \to  \gamma -1 $ where I understand the $-1$ at the moment as confirmation for your final remark. I still have to check/understand this and its whereabouts...

Comment: Where do you get the $\Gamma$ function from? Maybe using the identity 25.12.6 in https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12 is easier.

Comment: The gamma-function comes from trying to match the hypothese of equality of the sum with the $\Gamma(-1)$ - renormalization. If I find any valid expression for the regularization of the sum, I'd like it to equal the regularization of the $\Gamma(-1)$ - that would either back the validity of the expression, or forbid the hand-waving-equating in my second table (which would either be a respectable result)...

Comment: Hmm, the dlmf.nist.gov - equation gives some expression involving the truncated mercator-series; I do not see how to proceed with this .`h=exp(60);hi=1/h; w=polylog(2,0+1/h)+polylog(2,1-1/h)-zeta(2) ; ex=8;(w + log(h)*sum(k=1,ex,hi^k/k))*h^ex` gives a vanishing error when $1/h$ goes to zero. But what can I take from this?

Comment: What do you mean by truncated mercator series? For $x\rightarrow 1$ you have $$\frac{{\rm Li_2}(x)}{1-x} = \frac{-{\rm Li_2}(1-x) + \zeta(2) - \ln(x)\ln(1-x)}{1-x} \, .$$ The second term diverges as $\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $x\rightarrow 1$ and the third diverges as $\ln(1-x)$ with contributions ${\cal O}\left( (1-x)\ln(1-x) \right)$ that vanish in the limit. For the first term we have $${\rm Li_2}(1-x) = (1-x) + {\cal O}\left( (1-x)^2 \right) \, . $$

Comment: You basically add "counter"-terms for the "naked" singularities. Here: $$\frac{\zeta(2)}{1-x} \quad \text{and} \quad \ln(1-x) \, .$$

Comment: The "truncation" came into play when I tried to approximate `w` in my codesnippet, just empirically - detecting that the truncated mercator-series does the job, with more & more terms - after which it "clicked" in my brain that this is of course the log-term $\ln(1-x)$ in the formula... *grrmpf*

Comment: @diger can you "throw away the divergent part" if the constant part of the expansion contains a divergent part, e.g. zeta(1).

Comment: Can you show me an example where this happens?

Comment: Almost any function with order (1/n). Because this is a sum over 1/n^2  the new order would be in terms of 1/n, and thuse regularised when not alternating to any power, is expected to something in terms of zeta(1). Ofcourse you can assign a value but that would be like saying $\zeta(1)=\gamma$ while that is not the regularized value. Another example would be ln(n)/n. The regularized value diverges, which is ironically in my opinion a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you want to say. I try to sum up what I think you want to say: Here the sum is over $1/n^2$ means the inner sum $\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j^2}$, right? Then you say the new order would be in terms of $1/n$, so here $1/k$, right? But this new order is a constant for large $k$, namely $\zeta(2)$. That constant is the reason for the pole $\frac{1}{1-x}$ since for $x\rightarrow 1$ the main contribution is essentially from a geometric series. Can you write down a very specific example, so I see what you want to say?

Answer (score 1):

Similair as above but more in line with the rest of the picure you posted

The eulerian numbers(s,n): $\Delta^{s+1}n^s$ cut-off at 1. (so you ignore 0 and bellow when delta'ing).

Upper limit when s is positive integer s btw.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ Eulerian.numbers(s,n) c^n}{(1-c)^{s+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n n^s$

Now at the negative side:

Eulerian numbers(-s,n): $.^{s-1}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m^{-s}$ (the s'th -1 'indefinite' sum, I aways struggled with notation for this cause it's just similair to a multiple integral).

In your case with s=-2.
Eulerian numbers(-2,n): $\sum_{n=1}^{k}n^{-2}$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{k}n^{-2} c^n(1-c)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n n^{-2}$

You can "see it" by (1-c) which works like  a delta operator.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{k}n^{-2} c^n=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^n n^{-2}}{1-c}$$

From here on figure the limit as c goes to 1, by expending the polynomal. What the answer previous stated before was that you could disregard the divergent parts, which is I think incorrect, e.g. zeta(1) which is also here the case I think.

An intuitive example:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{c^n}{n^2 (1-c)}$$
Let  c goes to 1+h with h being small. Only looking at the $h^0$ order gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+h)^n}{n^2 (-h)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{n}=-\zeta(1)$$

Now like you normally would (or see directly from it series it's going to contain a full zeta(1)).

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{k}n^{-2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\pi^2/6-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{1}{6k^3}+\frac{1}{30k^5}-...$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^kn^{-2}=\bigg(\pi^2/6-\sum_{j=-1}^{\infty}\zeta(-j)(k^{-2-j}) \frac{(-2)!}{(-2-j)!(j)!}\bigg)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{k}n^{-2}=-\pi^2/12-\sum_{j=-1}^{\infty}\zeta(-j)\zeta(2+j) \frac{(-2)!}{(-2-j)!(j)!}$$
And as you see $\zeta(1)$ is part of the sum at j=-1 twice and it will only gets reduced once by (-1)!. There for the regularized value got a pole, e.g. contains zeta(1).

Or better writen:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{S\infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{k}n^{-2}=-\zeta(1)-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\zeta(-j)\zeta(2+j) (-1)^{j+1} (j+1) $$

And even though the other sum also diverges it seems unlikely it contains zeta(1) but yeah it needs a more convincing argument/needs to be regularized first aswell. But it seems to be regulaziable.

Ps: doesn't it alternate in the picture? And thuse is trivial. It's used for c isn't 1 to very easily calculate the zeta function. I'd say it's the basics. Cause if it doesn't alternate you also get for sum 1/n just zeta(1) in the entry before.

Comment: Hi Gerben! Regarding the last three/four formulae: I feel, this should be somehow equivalent with my partial sum-formula (2.2) $ S_2(N) \to (1+N) H_2(N) - H_1(N)$ which throws something like $(1+N) \zeta(2) - \zeta(1)$ into the scene. ($H_2(n)= \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^2$ and $H_1(n)= \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$). I'm not sure that your final thoughts go into this direction?

Comment: From the suggestion in the table I expect the regularized sum is the regularized $\Gamma(-1)$. But even with this I've two incompatible ideas. On one hand we would expect $(-2)! = (-1)!/-1 \underset{\mathcal R}=-\gamma /-1 = \gamma$ on the other hand the Cauchy principal value should be $(\Gamma(-1+1/h)+\Gamma(-1-1/h))/2 \to 1-\gamma$ for $h \to 0$. So this is in all three ways not so simple ... :-(

Comment: In the table you calculate the alternating sum, atleast the result seems to indicate that. And I do not see how 2.2 is derived. Cause you sum over H_2(N) and then? E. G. In the table you have in enter 3, 1-4+1=-2. And sum (-1)^(n+1)/n =ln(2). Those are all alternating. Why isn't this alternating and thuse easy.

Comment: I derived $S_2(N)$ this way: $S_2(3)=1 + (1+1/4) + (1+1/4+1/9)= 3 \cdot 1/1^2 + 2\cdot 1/2^2+1\cdot 1/3^2 = (4-1)/1^2 + (4-2)/2^2+(4-3)/3^2 = 4(1/1^2+1/2^2+1/3^2) - (1/1+1/2-1/3) $ which when generalized to upper limit $N$ is  $S_2(N) = (N+1) H_2(N) - H_1(N)$

Comment: The *alternating* sums are easy to find numerically, and I've also seen them somewhere in literature. The *non-alternating* rowsums I've seen in literature but only for *non-negative* row-indices. But I think the hypothese of the *non-alternating* sums being $\Gamma()$ at zero and at negative integers is strongly backed by the observation (not made here, but also have been seen in literature) that *generalizing* row-indices to fractional positive values agree with $\Gamma()$ at the same fractional values.

Comment: Ahh, now I begin to understand the $(1-c)$ term in the denominator of your formula. I understand now, that I always worked with the approximation $1+c$ and didn't see, that $1+c+c^2+...$ would be a better, and eventually, perfect approximation which is only that un-understood $1/(1-c)$ expression. Heureka! I shall see now, how my problems hopefully begin to disappear... Thanks for that point.

Comment: ... and in my earlier comment the problem with $\Gamma(-1)\overset?=\Gamma(0)/-1$ is resolved by the completion $\Gamma(-1+h)/\Gamma(0+h) = -1/(1-h)$. This shall help me in revisiting many of my unfinished notes.

Comment: Your notation for the $2$'nd $-1$th indefinite sum is an amazing idea, btw. I'll see whether I'll adapt that.

Comment: Ok yeah seeing 2.2. Can be generalised for higher order sums by the negative delta writen as binominal btw.

Comment: So yeah that works aswell but is making life a bit (unnecessary I think) complicated. What you have to do is then is "delta" N, and then regularize it over big N in your formula, because i do not have another methode to regularize a function as limit to inf. So you get $\zeta(2)-\zeta(1)+\sum_{n=1}^{S\infty}\Delta(n H_{2}(n))$

Comment: Chain rule (and you can manipulte it this way similair to how you are used to manipulte integrals, but to see it's "true" $\Delta (f(n)g(n))=f(n)\Delta g(n)+g(n)\Delta f(n)-\Delta f(n)\Delta g(n)$ thuse $\sum_{n=1}^{S\infty}\Delta(n H_{2}(n))=\sum_{n=1}^{S\infty} H_2(n)+1/n-1/n^2$ which boils down to the $\sum H_2(n)$

Comment: I don't think your approach works. For $c=1+h$ the series is not convergent, so if at all you would have to work with $c=1-h$ ($h>0$) s.t. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-h)^n}{n^2 h} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{h} + \frac{1}{h} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-h)^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \binom{n}{k} \, .$$ This is not a valid resummation, since the coefficient $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \binom{n}{k}$$ is divergent for every $k=1,2,3...$. The reason why this happens is because you lack the logarithmic singularity if you want to find the regularized value by analytic continuation.

Comment: Working with 1-h seems alright cause it should be valid if |c|=1 and then if you take c=1-h you can neclect the img. Part, and have to look of the correction term matters. I neclectend the correction term, and use it more like a short cut to get a gut feeling. Didn't looked into the correction term. Will work both out. Need to find some time to write it down. You can also say the negative factorials are the sum of the (shifted up collums in Wikipedia) Stirling numbers of the second (to double check if regularizing them really works for the finite value, nevered applied this).

Comment: While in principle it is ok to look for orders and neglect correction terms as you mention it, it only works when you isolated/separated the bare singularities. Otherwise there is no power-series expansion about $h=0$ and you can see in this example what happens if you still do it and how math tries to tell you you have done something terribly wrong. You can only argue this way after you have taken care of all the possible singularities.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make much sense.

For $\Re(s) > 3$
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} ((n+1)^{3-s}-n^{3-s}) \sum_{m=1}^n m^{-s} = -\zeta(2s-3)$$

Then $$\lim_{s\to 2} -\zeta(2s-3)= \infty$$
but $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}-\Re(\zeta(2(2+it+t^3)-3)=-\gamma$$

Comment: Hmm, but if we detect a contradiction, the question does not make sense? Contradiction is a tool to arrive at a disproof, not to tell the asker the meta-information that their conjecturing/asking makes no sense...?

Comment: It is fun that my answer is downvoted whereas it is the only one showing a summation method giving a value to your divergent series. $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\Re(\zeta(1+it+t^3))=\gamma$ is the easiest way to assign a finite value to $\sum 1/n$

Comment: @Gerben I don't understand your comment. I am showing how to regularize to get $-\gamma$ for the OP's divergent series (and $\gamma$ for $\sum 1/n$)

Comment: I know, and it's obvious the correct answer if you want to assign a finite value. I personally just wouldn't say the regularized value has to be a finite value, as either negative or positive infinity makes more sense in the context of analysing the factorial, just like $\sum 1/n \neq \gamma$. Thats all. Given no one posted the correct answer yet I do think it should be upvoted, but i that's just me. Although the updated question claims a different answer.